# Binding my changing data context in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've seen slight variations on this request - but I'm having a hard time getting this to work for my situtaion.  I have a application where a user selection of a combobox will drive an event.  That even grabs data from the database and I want to bind that data to the UI.  I thought I had my binding set up correclty, but I can't get anything to happen.  I can see all my code calculation firing correctly, but I don't see any feedback regarding the binding.  I'm pretty new to WPF and still trying to wrap my head around it (I come from MVC web world) so any pointers are much appreciated.  Thanks.

MainWindow Code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}

private void cboAllClients_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindowViewModel vm = DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
    listClient selectedClient = e.AddedItems[0] as listClient;
    Credit.Calc c = new Credit.Calc();
    c.CalcCredit(selectedClient.ClientName);
    vm.FFCredits = c.FundFamilyCredits;
    vm.FundCredits = c.FundCredits;
    DataContext = vm;
}
```

main window xaml (abbreviated to binding issue)

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbFundFamily" Width="auto" Height="auto"
         Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListBox.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="FFCredits"></Binding>
    </ListBox.DataContext>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FundFamilyName}"
                           Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                           Background="White" FontSize="14" Foreground="Black">
                </TextBlock>
                <!--<Rectangle Width="{Binding Path=BrokerCreditList.Utilization}"
                               Height="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Rectangle>-->
                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BrokerCreditList.}"></TextBlock>-->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public List<listClient> AllClients { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FundFamilySum> FFCredits { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FundSum> FundCredits { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        using (AgencyModelEntities db = new AgencyModelEntities())
        {
            AllClients = db.listClients.ToList();
            FFCredits = new ObservableCollection<FundFamilySum>();
            FundCredits = new ObservableCollection<FundSum>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you reposted your xaml code by accident as the mainviewmodel, could you update it?

Comment: Remove the SelectionChanged event and bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to some relevant property in the ViewModel. MVVM eliminates the need for most UI events by using simple bindings and INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Your MainWindowViewModel looks like XAML.   Shouldn't it be C#?

Comment: Your ViewModel needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I believe you want your ListBox to have ItemsSource="{Binding FFCredits}" instead of that DataContext Binding.

Comment: Also, remove the `DataContext = vm;` statement, you should only set the `DataContext` once.

Comment: @Murkaeus, just tried that but no dice.  Thanks.  I'm going to look up implementing INotifyPropertyChanged for the viewmodel now.

Comment: @user576838 That wasn't going to fix everything, it was just one of the fixes you need to implement, that's why I only made it a comment instead of an answer :P.

Comment: @Murkaeus, cool thanks!  I really appreciate the pointers - still very new to WPF!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially when the view is loaded, the `ListBox` is bound to `vm.FFCredits` which is `new ObservableCollection<FundFamilySum>();`

But the view does not know that the FFCredits has changed unless a PropertyChanged notification is raised so it is still bound to `new ObservableCollection<FundFamilySum>();`.

I think you are expecting the changes to be picked up as you are setting `DataContext = vm` again. But this will not work as `vm` was already the `DataContext`.

Comment: Thanks @cheedep.  I'm looking into into implementing inotifyproperty for the viewmodel.  Gotta find a good article.  Thanks again.

Comment: You may implement it in your BaseViewModel if it is not already there, if it is, all you need to do is raise PropertyChanged